# What is my phpmyadmin's url?

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie with linux ubuntu and phpmyadmin. I had an url to access phpmyadmin thru the webbrowser, but since i did not use it for like a year now, i can't remember the url.

I believe it was something like - example ip: 123.123.123.123/phpMyAdmin
But when I change that to my actual server's ip, it doesn't work.

Is there a file that shows which url to use to access phpmyadmin?

Problem solved, I had to include port after the ip for it to work ^^

Comment: Is it a local or remote site? if local: http://localhost/phpmyadmin otherwise it would indeed be http://{ipaddress}/phpmyadmin  I would start by making sure all the server software is running (apache, mysql etc).

Comment: It's not on local network. Is it possible that I somehow turned it off after a server reboot? What's the command to check if mysql, apache and phpmyadmin is runing?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql` and `ps -ef | grep apache` Phpmyadmin is not something that has a server instance (it is software that runs under apache and with mysql (or another webserver/sqlserver).

Comment: I have posted above what it wrote after those commands. Is it runing?

Answer (score 2):

Find apache.conf file of phpMyAdmin, regularly, it’s under /etc/phpmyadmin/ on Linux environment. Please edit this file with root authority：

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration 

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Change this –“Alias /phpadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin” like this one ”

Alias /secretcode /usr/share/phpmyadmin, secretcode stands for a series of letters as a symbol, but hard to recognize, for instance ‘@34%6tFd&hs’. So:

# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration 
Alias /@34%6tFd&hs /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Restart your web-server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now you may try the new URL